# Is there a reference for compact imbedding of Hölder space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, holder-spaces

Suppose $0<\alpha <\beta$. Then, the Hölder space $C^\beta$ is compactly imbedded to $C^\alpha$. See the Wikipedia article [Hölder condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition).

However, I could not find precise reference from some books on functional analysis.

1. Can anybody  indicate a precise reference for this theorem?
2. If possible, I would like to know a reference on the similar result on parabolic Hölder space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Lemma 6.33 in [Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order](http://books.google.com/books?id=eoiGTf4cmhwC) by Gilbarg and Trudinger. A proof is also presented by Ngô Quốc Anh on [his blog](http://anhngq.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/compact-embedding-of-holder-spaces/). It's quite simple. Take a bounded family of functions in $C^\beta(\Omega)$. Extend them continuously to $\overline{\Omega}$ (uniform continuity allows that). Apply the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem to extract a uniformly convergent subsequence. Since 
$$\|u_m-u_n\|_{C^\alpha} \le \|u_m-u_n\|_{C^\beta}^{\alpha/\beta} (\sup |u_m-u_n|)^{1-\alpha/\beta} \tag1$$
it follows that $(u_m)$ is Cauchy in $C^\alpha$.

A parabolic Hölder space is a Hölder space with respect to a particular metric on $\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R$, like $\rho((x,t),(x',t'))=|x-x'|+|t-t'|^{1/2}$. The above argument applies irrespective of the metric. All that matters is that the domain has a compact closure, so  that the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem can be applied.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.