# Is the closure of the unit ball in $C^2[0,1]$ compact in $C^1[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is the closure of the  unit ball in $C^2[0,1]$ compact in $C^1[0,1]$?

I don't know how to represent the ball in $C^2[0,1]$ with norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ or some other norm, I think this problem should use Arzela-Ascoli Theorem.

Comment: Yes, Ascoli is the way to go. On $C^2([0,1])$, your norm is something equivalent to $$\lVert f\rVert_{C^2} = \max \left\{\lVert f\rVert_\infty, \lVert f'\rVert_\infty, \lVert f''\rVert_\infty \right\}.$$

Comment: Yes, in this way, we are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, I'll modify the answer in [Is there a reference for compact imbedding of Hölder space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450028/) to fit this situation.

Take a bounded family of functions $(u_n)$ in $C^2([0,1])$. This implies $u_n$, $u_n'$, and $u_n''$ are uniformly bounded. By the mean value theorem, $u_n$ and  $u_n'$ are equicontinuous. By the Ascoli-Arzelà theorem, we can  extract a   subsequence $v_k = u_{n_k}$ such that $v_k$ and $v_k'$  converge uniformly. This subsequence is Cauchy in $C^1[0,1]$ and therefore converges.