# Prove that $X$ is relatively compact in the space of continuous functions on $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness, equicontinuity

Let $X$ be the set of real-valued functions $g:\mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ of class $C^2$, with support in $[-1,1]$, and such that $\int_{-1}^1(g'')^2\le1$.

I am interested in proving that the closure of $X$ in the space of continuous functions on the interval $[-1,1]$ is compact, but I am absolutely stumped on how to proceed. So any help will be very useful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the "suppose that" conditions supposed to be additional defining features of the set $X$?

Comment: @Alan Yes, that's right.

Comment: Is $X$ the set of *all* functions $g$ of class $C^2$ with support in $[-1,1]$ and such that $\int(g'')^2\le1$?

Comment: @AnneBauval That's right.

Comment: Do you know Arzela-Ascoli-Theorem? I have not figured out the details, but it seems applicable here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any $g\in X$ and $x\in[-1,1]$, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$|g'(x)|=\left|\int_{-1}^xg''(t)\,dt\right|\le\|1\|_{L^2[-1,1]}=\sqrt2$$
[hence $X$ is equicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity#Examples) and every $X(x)\subset\mathbb R$ is bounded (by $2\sqrt2$).
The conclusion follows by [Arzelà-Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Compact_metric_spaces_and_compact_Hausdorff_spaces).

Comment: $g'(-1)=0$ since the support of $g$ is contained in $[-1,1]$. @Luca.b

Comment: Yes, sorry, my fault. And also my proof relies on this, since Poincaré inequality is true only when you have zero trace.

Comment: @AnneBauval Right. In fact this point is a bit confusing since the question does not give informations on the domain of the functions $g$.

Comment: @Gerd When one writes "differentiable with support in $[-1,1]$", the domain *a priori* is *always* $\mathbb R$, or at least some $(a,b)\supset[-1,1]$, which finally comes down to the same thing. But if you find a better way to edit the question, please do!

Comment: It suffices to write $g\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ and it would be much clearer

Comment: @AnneBauval I did.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Since each $g$ has support in $[-1,1]$ you can consider each $g \in X$ to be a solution of the Dirichlet boundary value problem $u''(t)=g''(t)$ $(t \in [-1,1])$, $u(-1)=u(1)=0$. Thus for each $g \in X$
$$
g(t)= \int_{-1}^1 G(t,s) g''(s) ds \quad (t \in [-1,1]) \quad (1)
$$
where $G: [-1,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is Green's function for this boundary value problem. This also yields
$$
g'(t)= \int_{-1}^1 G_t(t,s) g''(s) ds \quad (t \in [-1,1]) \quad (2)
$$
and since $G$ and $G_t$ are bounded on $[-1,1]^2$ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives uniform bounds $\beta_0,\beta_1$ with $\|g\|_\infty \le \beta_0$ and $\|g'\|_\infty \le \beta_1$ for each $g \in X$. Now you can apply Arzela-Ascoli.

Green's functions here is
$$
G(t,s)=-(1-t)(s+1)/2 ~~ (-1 \leq s \leq t \leq 1), \quad G(t,s)=-(1-s)(t+1)/2 ~~ (-1 \leq t \leq s \leq 1).
$$
With that you can also verify (1) and (2) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I=(-1,1)$ and let $g\in X$. Since $g,g',g''\in C(\overline{I})\subseteq L^2(I)$, you have that $g\in W_0^{2,2}(I)$. By [Poincaré inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality)(iterated two times), you get that $\lVert g\rVert_{W^{2,2}(I)}\leq c\lVert g''\rVert_{L^2(I)}\leq c$.

So you have that $X$ is a bounded subset of $W^{2,2}(I)$. Now use the [compact embedding theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002709/reference-request-for-sobolev-embedding-for-the-case-pn) in the case $pk>n$ and you get that:
$$ W^{2,2}(I) \xrightarrow{compact} C^{o,\gamma}(\overline I)\hookrightarrow C(\overline{I}), \qquad \gamma<1/2$$
So $X$ is relatively compact in $C(\overline{I})$